# BFS and DFS tree traversal

Tags: algorithm, scala, tree

I posted some code as part of an answer to another [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62744) and I thought it would be a good idea to get that code reviewed also.

Any comments are welcomed, but I am mostly annoyed by `terminalNode`.  It is basically a slightly convenient factory method, but I think it should either be renamed to something more enlightening, or something entirely different should be done.

```
object TreeTraversal extends App {

  case class Node[+T](value: T, left: Option[Node[T]], right: Option[Node[T]]) {
    def map[V](f: T => V): Node[V] = 
      Node(f(value), left.map(l => l.map(f)), right.map(r => r.map(f)))
    def childrenLeftRight: List[Node[T]] = List(left, right).flatten
  }
  def terminalNode[T](value: T) = Node(value, None, None)

  def dfs[T](tree: Node[T]): List[T] = {
    var output = List[T]()
    tree.map(t => (output = t :: output))
    output.reverse
  }

  def bfs[T](tree: Node[T]): List[T] = {
    @tailrec
    def bfsLoop(accum: List[List[T]], nextLayer: List[Node[T]]): List[T] = nextLayer match {
      case Nil => accum.reverse.flatten
      case _ => bfsLoop(nextLayer.map(_.value) :: accum, nextLayer.flatMap(_.childrenLeftRight))
    }
    bfsLoop(List[List[T]](), List(tree))
  }

  val tree1 = Node[Int](6, Some(Node(13, Some(terminalNode(101)), None)), Some(Node(42, Some(terminalNode(666)), Some(terminalNode(65)))))
  println("map: " + tree1.map(i => s"Hello$i"))
  println("dfs: " + dfs(tree1))
  println("bfs: " + bfs(tree1))
}
```

`Node` looks like a monad.  Could I get all other operations such as flatMap and foldLeft for free somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any comments are welcomed, but I am mostly annoyed by `terminalNode`

From my opinion, it's more natural to provide default values for case classes:

```
case class Node[+T](value: T, left: Option[Node[T]] = None, right: Option[Node[T]] = None) {//...
```

Then you can simply use `Node(42)` anywhere in your code.

> Node looks like a monad. Could I get all other operations such as `flatMap` and `foldLeft` for free somehow?

Typically, any methods in Monads are based on `flatMap` and `unit` methods. Therefore you need to implement `flatMap` method, as `unit` method you already have (`Node.apply`).

`flatMap` needs to accept a method, which returns new instance of `Node`, e.g. `def flatMap[V](f: T => Node[V]): Node[V]`. Then it should look like the following:

```
def flatMap[V](f: T => Node[V]): Node[V] = {
    f(value).copy(
      left = left.map(_.flatMap(f)),
      right = right.map(_.flatMap(f))
    )
}
```

And it you create a new test, it produce the same output, as for `map`:

```
println("map: " + tree1.map(i => s"Hello$i"))
println("fmap: " + tree1.flatMap(i => Node(s"Hello$i"))) //will be the same outputs
```

But, you should handle cases, when `f(value)` may return new node with existing `left` and/or `right` values, otherwise the implementation above may override the result. You need to consider this in your final implementation.

Then, according to the rule of `map`, it can be present as `map(f) = fmap unit f`, so you can create method `map2` with `flatMap`:

```
def map2[V](f: T => V): Node[V] =
  flatMap(t => Node(f(t)))
```

Then you will have the same outputs:

```
println("map: " + tree1.map(i => s"Hello$i"))
println("map2: " + tree1.map2(i => s"Hello$i")) //will be the same outputs
```

Regarding `foldLeft`: typically you can almost [everything](http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/07/30/lots-and-lots-of-foldleft-examples/) implement with `foldLeft`, but not otherwise. So we need to understand, what `foldLeft` should do (DSF?), and then we can express other methods with this.

Also couple notes, I'd change (it's arguable, of course, but worth considering):

- Instead of `left.map(l => l.map(f)` I'd use `left.map(_.map(f))`
- `tree.map(t => (output = t :: output))` this can be replaced with mutable [ArrayBuffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer) for 2 reasons: it should be slightly faster and slightly more well-looking.

Consider this code:

```
 def dfs2[T](tree: Node[T]): List[T] = {
   val output = ArrayBuffer[T]()
   tree.map(output += _)
   output.toList
 }
```

And outputs again will be the same:

```
println("dfs: " + dfs(tree1))
println("dfs2: " + dfs2(tree1)) //will be the same outputs
```

Hope that helps.